# SpecExplorer how to sort Microsoft.Modeling.Sequence

Tags: c#, sorting, testing, specifications

I am using SpecExplorer to generate a test suite. I have one function that should return a sorted collection of strings (same sort behaviour as List.Sort()).

In the model I am using a Microsoft.Modeling.Sequence. It is not possible to use a List because SpecExplorer can't evaluate the current state if you are using lists...

My question is:
How can I return a sorted Microsoft.Modeling.Sequence without using lists... I know I could compare all strings with each other and with every compare step create a new immutable sequence, but this seems too complex. Is there an easier solution?

OffTopic: There is no SpecExplorer Tag...

EDIT:

a current working example

```
Sequence<string> toSort = new Sequence<string>(new string[] { "Delta", "delta", "Alpha", "Gamma", "Beta" });
Sequence<string> sorted = new Sequence<string>();

while (toSort.Count != 0)
{
    int currentMaxIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < toSort.Count; i++)
        if (currentMaxIndex == -1 || toSort[i].CompareTo(toSort[currentMaxIndex]) < 0)
            currentMaxIndex = i;
    sorted = sorted.Add(toSort[currentMaxIndex]);
    toSort = toSort.RemoveAt(currentMaxIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some questions:

- To your function which should return a sorted sequence: Is this function used in the model i.e. in rule-methods and is the sequence a rule argument?
- Assuming yes: Why do you want to model a sorted sequence at all? In a sequence by definition the order is important. If you sort the sequence the order is not important, because the order is always the same: the defined sort order?
- This is the reason why the Microsoft.Modeling.Sequence has no sort function and having one is not very important.
- If all this is the case you can use in your model a rule argument of type Microsft.Modeling.Set. Your model explorations will be much smaller, faster and cleaner and also any cord scenarios, which might somehow try to slice the state space.
- If your sequence is not a rule argument you can easily use any c# code (e.g. lists). Spec Explorer should not have any problem with it.
- If you really need sorting due to an unknown reason maybe Linq can make your code shorter, nicer ...